# Angular clearinterval not stopping interval

Tags: angular, setinterval, clearinterval

I have following code where I start an Interval for changing page title when the user is on different tab and I receive an event from a Subject:

```
let that = this;
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
  if (document.hidden) {
    that.desktopNotificationService.desktopNotifSubject.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((event) => {

      that.blinkInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (that.titleService.getTitle() === that.origTitle) {
          console.log('setting title notif');
          that.titleService.setTitle(that.appTitleNotif);
        } else {
          console.log('setting title orig');
          that.titleService.setTitle(that.origTitle);
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('clearing interval');
    clearInterval(that.blinkInterval);
    that.titleService.setTitle(that.origTitle);
  }
}, false);
```

Even after 'clearing interval' gets printed, i.e. when clearInterval() is invoked, still the interval keeps running

```
setting title orig 
setting title notif
setting title orig 
setting title notif
clearing interval
setting title orig 
setting title notif
```

How can I stop the interval in else block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClearInterval clearing the interval but not clearing the subscription, that you have subscribed to. It still there and executing the same line.

```
let that = this;
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
  let sub ;
  if (document.hidden) {

sub=that.desktopNotificationService.desktopNotifSubject.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((event) => {

      that.blinkInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (that.titleService.getTitle() === that.origTitle) {
          console.log('setting title notif');
          that.titleService.setTitle(that.appTitleNotif);
        } else {
          console.log('setting title orig');
          that.titleService.setTitle(that.origTitle);
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('clearing interval');
    clearInterval(that.blinkInterval);
    that.titleService.setTitle(that.origTitle);
    if(sub){
      sub.unsubscribe();// this will do the trick
    }
  }
}, false);
```